# Multinomial Regression Model with random effects

Tags: categorical-data, multinomial-distribution, effects

I have unordered categorical data (behavior with subclasses) as response variable with more than 2 classes. My independent variables are continuous and categorical. I would like to run a multinominal model (with multinom function).

```
model<-multinom(Y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)^2, data = data)
```

However, since the study has nested factors, I would like to add random factors to the model (r1 and r2). Which way is the best to do so? How can I write the formula?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "ordinal unordered categorical data"?

Comment: Hi, yes of course, sorry! My response variable in this case is a sort of behavior with 5 subclasses (all categorical e.g. jumping, running, standing...) but without any ranking in the subclasses - they are all weighted the same. Hope this helps... I've tried to add the random factors from glmm + (1|ID), but then I get the error message "operations are possible only for numeric logical or complex types"

Comment: How is that ordinal?

Comment: I've changed the text!